# JQuery .on() and .off() don't work the way I'm using them

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events, event-handling

I have a page where I trigger an ajax load event when the user scrolls down to a certain portion of the page. I have the following ajax event handlers here:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
$('#loader').show();
$(window).off('scroll');
    }); 

$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $('#loader').hide();
  $(window).on('scroll');
    });
```

To prevent the ajax event from firing multiple times I turn off the scroll event handler at the beginning of an ajax call (I also wrote a delay function which will wait a few milliseconds before firing as well). My intention is to rebind the scroll after ajax is finished. I know these events are occurring because my #loader div is loading and unloading as designed. Unfortunately, the scroll never re-binds, it remains off and I cannot understand why. Hence, I load a single ajax page of new content then it stops working.

Comment: `$(window).on('scroll');` what are you binding here? There is no actual handler.

Comment: They work as designed. You aren't using them correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The names "on" and "off" may be confusing; you can't use them to switch events on and off.

The `off` method removes the event handler completely from the element. When you bind the event again, you have to specify the event handler:

```
$(window).on('scroll', handlerFunction);
```

Comment: I see. I was confused as I can turn off scroll with $(window).off('scroll') but can't turn it back on the same way.